# nginx rewrite: remove subdirectory and file extension from URL

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

Im super stuck here,  how do i turn mydomain.com/php/hello-world.php to mydomain.com/hello-word ... the below example only downloads my php file rather than display the contents.  Please help

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name mydomain.com www.mydomain.com;

        root /var/www/mydomain;
        index index.php;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /php$uri.php =404;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
        }

}
```

Comment: Try: `try_files $uri $uri/ /php$uri.php;`

Comment: well it sort of worked, but now i only get the option of downloading the php file instead of it actually displaying the php content

Comment: Strange, I would expect that behaviour if you added the `=404` on the end.

Comment: i did add it actually.  ill try to remove it and see if it works thanks